# How to redirect from modal content if opened without main window?

Tags: redirect, modal-dialog, search-engine

I have a little [page](http://greenhorn.esy.es/index.html) where sub-pages are loaded into a modal window. But search engines forwards the visitors to the subpages without the main window (for example to [this](http://greenhorn.esy.es/pages/content1.html) one).

I'm curious, is it possible to let the visitors see the main page with the sub-page opened in modal, instead of the content of the subpage only? Shall I try to compress the content of the subpages into the main page and somehow calling them via bookmarks (since I assume I cannot identify from a html whether it's opened into a modal window), but I am sure somebody more experienced can come up with a proper idea.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You could check the window.parent to see how it was opened.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it is a feasible solution.

```
function parentExists()
{
 return (parent.location == window.location)? false : true;
}

if(parentExists()) .... ;
else {
       window.location.replace("http:// ...... .com");
    }
```